# ffmpeg install on Solaris 11.3

Tags: ffmpeg, solaris

I have archive software that uses ffmpeg on a Solaris server to generate previews during the archive process. I have installed ffmpeg on the Solaris server following the steps [outlined here](https://www.opencsw.org/package/ffmpeg/)

It appears as though the package installs successfully but if I run 'ffmpeg' as root I receive '-bash: ffmpeg: command not found'. From what I understand, running this command is what needs to work for the archive software to be able to use ffmpeg. From a bit of research it looks like I either have to move the ffmpeg install location to somewhere else or define some path that points to the ffmpeg software. My Solaris knowledge is limited so I am not sure how to do either of those things. Could someone describe how to define the path or move the installed package to the correct location?

Thank you

Comment: First, don't move the package - that will break the packaging system - later updates would likely fail, for example.  Second, you haven't provided enough information to solve your problem.  **What** "archive software" are you referring to?

Comment: The Archive Software is Archiware P5. According to their support team running 'ffmpeg' as the root user **should** run ffmpeg regardless of the directory you are in. They say if that function works than their software should be able to use ffmpeg. Right noe running ffmpeg returns with '-bash: ffmpeg: command not found'

Comment: There's no documented way to configure this product so that it knows where `ffmpeg` is located?  The product just assumes it magically is going to work?

Comment: Does `find /opt/csw -name ffmpeg -print` show anything?